# Remove item from input button and from list?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

Here is my all problem -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown-fill-empty-uecsjw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Current occurrence.

When I select a few items from the drop-down menu and delete them on the button called 'Remove' on the deleted one from the listener in the input button it looks as if it is still selected and checked ( from input ).

I know the reason. Because when I click on the button and call the function I do not trigger on selection and there is no removedItems.

Question is it possible to delete the selected item on the button ( function removeTemplate ) and delete it in my input?

I am using devExreme component which inside have method removedItems but i need to remove and on click on button.

Code is here:

```
   trainingSelected(e) {
    this.newItems = this.selectedPlans.filter(
      p => !e.removedItems.includes(p)
    );
    this.newItems.push(...e.addedItems);
    console.log('new items, ' , this.newItems);
    this.selectedPlans = this.newItems;
  }

    removeTemplate(e, training){
    console.log(e)
    console.log(training)
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.existingIndex = this.selectedPlans.indexOf(training);
    this.selectedPlans.splice(this.existingIndex , 1);
    // this.newItems.filter(item => item.id !== training.id) 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course we can delete the displayed value. To do this we need to take the reference for `dx-tag-box` component. I present two ways.

### Solution 1: Template reference

- `<dx-tag-box #tagBox`  add the template reference to dx-tag-box html tag
- send `tagBox` as param of removeTemplate function
  `<small (click)="removeTemplate($event, training, tagBox);" >`

On html

```
<dx-tag-box #tagBox [items]="trainingPlan" displayExpr="name" valueExpr="id" [showSelectionControls]="true" required
    searchEnabled="true" noDataText="Ne postoji trening templato" placeholder="Izaberite trening templato"
    showClearButton="true" deferRendering="false" (onSelectionChanged)="trainingSelected($event)"
    selectAllMode="allPages" applyValueMode="useButtons">
</dx-tag-box>


<div *ngFor="let training of selectedPlans">
    <div class="py-3">
        <p> {{ training.id }} <small (click)="removeTemplate($event, training, tagBox);" > Remove </small> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

On ts

```js
removeTemplate(e, training, tagBoxRef) {  // <-- reference
    this.existingIndex = this.selectedPlans.indexOf(training);
    this.selectedPlans.splice(this.existingIndex, 1);

    // Remove the value by index from tagBox reference.
    const displayedValue = tagBoxRef.value;
    const planIndexToRemove = displayedValue.findIndex(id => id === training.id);
    displayedValue.splice(planIndexToRemove, 1);
    tagBoxRef.value = displayedValue;
  }
```

**Working example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown-fill-empty-hczvpu

### Solution 2: ViewChild

Using ViewChild get the component reference without change the params of `removeTemplate` function

On html

- `<dx-tag-box #tagBox`   add the template reference to dx-tag-box html tag

On ts

- Create a reference for tagBox using ViewChild
  `@ViewChild("tagBox") tagBoxRef;` add this on top of AppComponent
- Use this.tagBoxRef to reference to tagBox component

```js
removeTemplate(e, training) {
    this.existingIndex = this.selectedPlans.indexOf(training);
    this.selectedPlans.splice(this.existingIndex, 1);

    // Remove the value by index from tagBox reference.
    const displayedValue = this.tagBoxRef.value;
    const planIndexToRemove = displayedValue.findIndex(id => id === training.id);
    displayedValue.splice(planIndexToRemove, 1);
    this.tagBoxRef.value = displayedValue;
  }
```

**Working example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown-fill-empty-s2ztmy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: awesome man awesome. 
Which solution you reccomend ?

Comment: I think so ViewChild is more cleaner, how ever take a look the documentation ensure the component is avalible when you call the reference

Answer (score 0):

That functionality might not be the best practice from a user experience perspective. Having two ways to accomplish the same thing could cause a user to think it is still selected in the box.

Unless there's a very specific and necessary use, I'd let the user just hit the "x" to remove the selected items since this is common practice.